# Keeping javascript variable's values in a browsing history

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm making a website generating content with javascript. 
I've a question about a simple code.
There is a php file rand.php:

```
<?php echo rand(1,5); ?>
```

and small html/javascript code

```
<a href="rand.php">rand.php</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        var obj = { 'title':'MyVal', 'value':0 };
        document.write(obj.title+': '+obj.value);
        //i don't want to get ajax-request if i go back of the history to here
        //only if i click link to here a first time, and here
        //i want to see a random number in [1,..,5] from a last visiting
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'rand.php',
                async: false,
                data: {},
                success: function(nr) {
                    obj.value = nr;
                }
            });     
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

and question is that if i click a rand.php -link and then i go back, but how to preserver the obj-JSON's values from a last visiting instead of getting a new ajax-request. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use cookies for saving data?

Comment: how in cookies. i like some examples.

Comment: Google has > 1000 as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/Guide/DOM/Storage#localStorage) to preserve persistent values on a per-client basis, without using cookies. The advantage of this approach over cookies is that with cookies, the values are sent along with every request. You wind up shuttling data back and forth that you might not even need, and it is possible for a cookie to be modified or overwritten on the server-side inadvertently.

To use local storage, you simply refer to the `localStorage` object, using `getItem` and `setItem`, to get and set data, respectively. If you anticipate supporting older clients, it is advisable to get a shim, or you can roll your own shim using cookies as a fallback.

**Documentation**

- localStorage on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FStorage#localStorage
- localStorage on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc848902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends quite a bit on what browsers you need to support, but local storage is pretty well-supported in the recent browsers. Docs here:

[The Storage object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/Guide/DOM/Storage)